# 2 way event-binding between parent and child components is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Working with an array of mapped items, I am attempting to toggle class in a child component, but state change in the parent component is not passed down to the child component.

I've tried a couple different approaches (using `{this.personSelectedHandler}` vs. `{() => {this.personSelectedHandler()}` in the **clicked** attribute, but neither toggled class successfully. The only class toggling I'm able to do affects ALL array items rendered on the page, so there's clearly something wrong with my binding.

**People.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Strapi from 'strapi-sdk-javascript/build/main';
import Person from '../../components/Person/Person';
import classes from './People.module.scss';
const strapi = new Strapi('http://localhost:1337');

class People extends Component {
    state = {
        associates: [],
        show: false
    };

    async componentDidMount() {
        try {
            const associates = await strapi.getEntries('associates');
            this.setState({ associates });
        }
        catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    }

    personSelectedHandler = () => {
        const currentState = this.state.show;
        this.setState({
            show: !currentState
        });

    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div className={classes.People}>
                {this.state.associates.map(associate => (
                    <Person
                        name={associate.name}
                        key={associate.id}
                        clicked={() => this.personSelectedHandler()} />
                ))}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default People;
```

**Person.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import classes from './Person.module.scss';
const baseUrl = 'http://localhost:1337';

const person = (props) => {
    let attachedClasses = [classes.Person];
    if (props.show) attachedClasses = [classes.Person, classes.Active];

    return (
        <div className={attachedClasses.join(' ')} onClick={props.clicked}>
            <img src={baseUrl + props.photo.url} alt={props.photo.name} />
            <p>{props.name}</p>
        </div>
    );
};

export default person;
```

(Using React 16.5.0)

Comment: you are trying to use props.show in the child, but you are not passing that prop from the parent.

Comment: In `Person.js`, try changing `onClick={props.clicked}` to `onClick={() => props.clicked()}`. In `People.js`, you can pass clicked as `click={this.personSelectedHandler}`.

Comment: Changing `onClick` and passing `show` to the child component results in all array items toggling class on click, not just clicked item.

Comment: Consider having show and click func in Person Component instead? This is because once `show` changes states on the parent class it will reflect on all child components using that state.

Comment: Makes sense..does that mean I need to change my child component from a function to a class?

Comment: Yes, functions are stateless. You could also use `Hooks` to set the states depending on which version of React you're on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, in your *People.js* component, change your person component to:

```
         <Person
          name={associate.name}
          key={associate.id}
          clicked={this.personSelectedHandler}
          show={this.state.show}}/>
```

You were *not passing the prop show* and also referring to a method inside the parent class is done this way. What @Shawn suggested, because of which all classes were toggled is happening because of Event bubbling.

In your child component *Person.js*, if you change your onClick to :

```
onClick={() => props.clicked()}
```

The parenthesis after props.clicked executes the function there. So, in your personSelectedHandler function, you either have to use ***event.preventDefault()*** in which case, you also have to pass event like this:

```
onClick={(event) => props.clicked}
```

and that should solve all your problems.

Here's a minimal sandbox for this solution:

[CodeSandBox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/m940j935mx)